# VS not debugging the current source file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

So when I hit *Debug*, VS did not seem to debug the current C++ source file (the source file of the project). Proof is that even after I deleted the main function in the current file, VS still debugged successfully, and printed something to the console. I guess it chose a source file from elsewhere to debug. Why did that happen? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you build in Debug Mode or Release Mode?  Release mode doesn't have as many symbols as Debug Mode.

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint before you run your program.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews A bit unfamiliar with all terminology involving all things exterior to the code itself... But Thanks!

Comment: I usually place breakpoints, then click on the "run" button.  The program will start and then stop at the place where you put the "breakpoint".  Search StackOverflow for "How to use a debugger".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you.

Comment: It runs the last known-good executable.  Use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "On Run,  when build or deployment errors occur" = Do not launch.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! Gotta try it out after work xxx